# Tika standalone app, metadata and content in the same output as plain text

Tags: apache-tika

I can't find a way to get an output from tika app that includes metadata and content in the same file as plain text. Anyone knows if it could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the app the only way to get a document that contains the metadata and extracted text is to output it in XML, HTML, or JSON recursive - if you need it in plain text you'll then have to do some post processing of that document (JSON is probably the easiest, using jq or the python json modules etc).

Depending on the output format you need, a simple alternative might be to just run the application twice, appending the output together:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.14.jar --metadata document.pdf > document.txt
java -jar tika-app-1.14.jar --text document.pdf >> document.txt
```